# How to diagonally split a matrix in four parts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I want to split a matrix in four parts from a specific index. On the illustration below, the index is the white square and I want to obtain four list containing the corresponding square (blue, green, yellow, purple). Squares on the diagonal are included with the ones on their 'relative' right.

How can I do that ?

[image: illustration]

Comment: How would you go about it on paper?
What have you tried so far?

Comment: @LinFelix I would compute square index that are on diagonals, then iterating on the matrix and try to figure out where to put each square based on their index relatively to the diagonals square index but I don't really know how to do it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most optimal solution but it is working:

```
def index_is_top(index_c, index_r, c, r):
  return r < index_r and ((c <= index_c and index_c - c <= index_r - r) or (c > index_c and c - index_c < index_r - r))

def index_is_bottom(index_c, index_r, c, r):
  return r > index_r and ((c >= index_c and index_c - c >= index_r - r) or (c < index_c and c - index_c > index_r - r))

def index_is_left(index_c, index_r, c, r):
  return c < index_c and ((r < index_r and index_r - r < index_c - c) or (r >= index_r and r - index_r <= index_c - c))

index_c, index_r = (1, 2)
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

tmp = [list(zip(l, range(len(l)))) for l in matrix]
tmp = zip(tmp, range(len(tmp)))
matrix_with_indices = [(n, c, r) for (sublist, r) in tmp for (n, c) in sublist]

# if you are deleting items from the matrix during these steps, then you can skip the "n not in top/bottom/left" checks
top = [n for (n, c, r) in matrix_with_indices if (index_is_top(index_c, index_r, c, r))]
bottom = [n for (n, c, r) in matrix_with_indices if (n not in top and index_is_bottom(index_c, index_r, c, r))]
left = [n for (n, c, r) in matrix_with_indices if (n not in top and n not in bottom and index_is_left(index_c, index_r, c, r))]
right = [n for (n, c, r) in matrix_with_indices if ((c != index_c or r != index_r) and n not in top and n not in bottom and n not in left)]

print(list(top))
print(list(left))
print(list(bottom))
print(list(right))

>> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
>> [9, 13]
>> [14, 15]
>> [4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 16]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).